# How to replace a @MockBean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Is it possible to replace an inherited `@MockBean` with the real `@Bean`?

I have an abstract class that defines many configurations and a setup for all ITests. Only for one single test I want to make use of the real bean, and not used the mocked one. But still inherit the rest of the configuration.

```
@Service
public class WrapperService {
       @Autowired
       private SomeService some;
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(...)
public abstract class AbstractITest {
    //many more complex configurations

    @MockBean
    private SomeService service;
}

public class WrapperServiceITest extends AbstractITest {
    //usage of SomeService should not be mocked
    //when calling WrapperService

    //using spy did not work, as suggested in the comments
    @SpyBean
    private SomeService service;;
}
```

Comment: `this is invalid` because of the `SomeService` is an Abstract class or any other reason?

Comment: I think u can use @SpyBean to use the real bean

Comment: @MehrajMalik because `@MockBean` is a mock and thus cannot be autowired as real bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way using a test `@Configuration` conditional on a property, and overriding that property in the impl with `@TestPropertySource`:

```
public abstrac class AbstractITest {    
    @TestConfiguration //important, do not use @Configuration!
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "someservice.mock", matchIfMissing = true)
    public static class SomeServiceMockConfig {
        @MockBean
        private SomeService some;
    }
}


@TestPropertySource(properties = "someservice.mock=false")
public class WrapperServiceITest extends AbstractITest {
    //SomeService will not be mocked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @SpyBean to use the real bean.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html

Comment: I tried, but did not work. The bean is still mocked, see my edit.

Comment: `@Autowired` will inject the mock itself.